# link to a specific ID

Tags: product-linking

O.K my site is on a demo server, and I am trying to link an image on a product page to a separate specific Product. I am trying a simple...

```
<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}3z-pro-3d-solidscape-printer-prototype-machine.html">productname</a>
```

However its not working, any ideas?

Comment: You need to get product in cms page?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR on a product page, in the description, i would like to make a link to another product

Answer (score 1):

You would need to pass the description through the correct parsing engine.

Eg. Output using

```
Mage::getSingleton('widget/template_filter')->filter($product->getDescription());
```

And set the URL in the description using standard shortcode syntax using the product link widget

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link" template="catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml"
     id_path="product/x"}}
```

Replace `x` with your product ID.

Answer (score 0):

To get URL of your product

```
 {{store url="3z-pro-3d-solidscape-printer-prototype-machine.html"}}
```

Refer this [link](http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url.html)